# How to AVAudioPlayer with progress bar show using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, uiprogressbar

I'm playing a song using `AVAudioPlayer`. I need a progress bar to show the progress of the song.

My issue is that the progress bar's progress isn't working properly. Within 2-3 seconds, it finishes its progress.

```
func playMusic() {

    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (currentSong?.mediaURL)!)
        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()


        updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(self.musicProgress))
        updater.frameInterval = 1
        updater.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)

        playButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "pause"), for: .normal)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
}

@objc func musicProgress()  {

    let normalizedTime = Float(self.player?.currentTime as! Double * 100.0 / (self.player?.duration as! Double) )
    self.progressMusic.progress = normalizedTime
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
let normalizedTime = Float(self.player?.currentTime as! Double * 100.0 / (self.player?.duration as! Double) )
```

With this you will get a value between `0.0` and `100.0`, but according to `UIProgressView` documentation, `progress` must be between `0.0` and `1.0`. Try

```
let normalizedTime = Float(self.player?.currentTime as! Double / (self.player?.duration as! Double) )
```

Comment: I don't think you're using `CADisplayLink` properly. That class should be used to update logic when UI is drawn, not update UI when logic changes. Try to use a regular timer instead, with interval like 0.05 seconds.

Comment: `CADisplayLink` not allow float value.

Comment: I meant you should try a regular `NSTimer`